# Adding/updating a Google Contact's photo

Tags: google-apps-script, put, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I am trying to update a Google Contacts contact's photo via URL using Google Apps Script.

The below is my attempt.

```
function addContactPhoto (blob) {
  var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.example.com/joe_bloggs.png");
  var options = {
   'method' : 'put',
   'contentType': 'image/png',
   'payload' : image.getBlob()
 };
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactID}', options);
}
```

I was trying to follow the instructions for the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo) by sending a `PUT` request to `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactID}` with the image as a Blob object in the payload.

Is this approach correct? I am having problems with getting the image URL being converted to the right object to be send through the URL. I would also like help with inserting the correct values of `userEmail` and `contactID`.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to set fields in that manner. Apps Script exposes a Contacts API built-in for amending normal fields: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/

Comment: Looks like photos are [read-only](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Photo) via the more recent People API, but the old protocol for [Contacts API is not](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact). If you are getting error messages, you should share them.

Answer (score 1):

For the payload, use `image.getBlob().getBytes()` for the correct image type.

You'll also need to use `OAuth2` for sending put requests. Add the line

```
options.headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + yourAccessToken
};
```

after you declare your options.